# How do I query a table based with HABTM relationship while providing additional conditions in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

How can i do this in CakePHP:
I'm using two tables (`regions` and `safaris`) having a many-to-many relationship. The tables are joined by another table called `regions_safaris` (with the fields `region_id` & `safari_id`). I want to fetch all `safaris` meeting a given criteria like durations of 5 days and in a given region. This should be implemented in CakePHP

Comment: You have asked the same question 3 times in as many hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

juma,

Please resist posting multiple times so quickly.

For more reference, please see the Cakebook Has-And-Belongs-To-Many relationship.  It is exactly what you're describing.  See http://book.cakephp.org/view/83/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM

In short, assuming you have the Cake models setup correctly (with the HABTM relationship established between regions, safaris, and regions_safaris; check the 'joinTable' index on the var $hasAndBelongsToMany array, in the models), you would do this:

```
   class SafariModel extends AppModel
   { 
     var $name = 'Safari';
     var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array( 'Tag'=>array( ..., 'joinTable'=>'regions_safaris', ... );

     function findSafaris( $duration = 5, $region = null )
     {
       return $this->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Region.region_name'=>$region, 'Safari.duration'=>$duration) );
     }
     ... // rest of class
   }
```